# Assigning MyScruct().var = results results in no assignment

Tags: swift, parsing, struct, swiftui

Ok.. probably bad title. But here, the problem.

```
struct DeckView: View {
    
    @State public var results = [ScryfallCard]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id ) { item in
            
            Mkae a list containing the results. 
            
        }.onAppear {
            ScryfallData().parseBulkData()
            print("Type of results::", type(of: results))
            print("results.capacity:", results.capacity)
        }
    }
}

struct ScryfallData {

    func parseBulkData() {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path!)
        var oracleFileName = ""
        
        for fileName in items {
            if fileName .hasPrefix("oracle-cards"){
                oracleFileName = fileName
            }
        }
        
        print("if let savedJson = Bundle.main.url")
        if let savedJson = Bundle.main.url(forResource: oracleFileName, withExtension: "") {
            if let dataOfJson = try? Data(contentsOf: savedJson) {
                print("if let dataOfJSON: \(dataOfJson)")
                do {
                    let scryfallDecodeData = try JSONDecoder().decode([ScryfallCard].self, from: dataOfJson)
                    print("scryfallDecodeData.capacity:", scryfallDecodeData.capacity)
                    
/* error here*/         DeckView().results = scryfallDecodeData
                    
                    print("DeckView().results: ", DeckView().results)
                    print("Decoded data:", type(of: scryfallDecodeData))
                } catch {
                    debugPrint("decode failed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting a blank List this in the debugger...

```
if let dataOfJSON: 73545913 bytes
scryfallDecodeData.capacity: 24391
DeckView().results:  []
Decoded data: Array<ScryfallCard>
Type of results:: Array<ScryfallCard>
results.capacity: 0
```

This means that oiver on the line marked Error Here, I'm asigning the decoded data to the DeckView().results var, but the end result is the data is not getting asigned. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are creating a new instance of DeckView(), you're then setting the data on that instance but referencing a different newly created instance in the print 'print("DeckView().results: ", DeckView().results)'. Besides that, a lot of this code looks wrong, what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be creating a `View` from view model (`ScryfallData`), but instead return the decoded data from the `parseBulkData` function and assign that to `results` inside the `onAppear` of your `View`.

Your models should never know about your UI. Your UI (`View` in case of SwiftUI) should own the models, not the other way around. This achieves good separation of concerns and also makes your business logic platform and UI agnostic.

```
struct DeckView: View {

    @State public var results = [ScryfallCard]()

    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id ) { item in
            Text(item.text)
        }.onAppear {
            self.results = ScryfallData().parseBulkData()
        }
    }
}

struct ScryfallData {
    func parseBulkData() -> [ScryfallCard] {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path!)
        var oracleFileName = ""

        for fileName in items {
            if fileName .hasPrefix("oracle-cards"){
                oracleFileName = fileName
            }
        }

        if let savedJson = Bundle.main.url(forResource: oracleFileName, withExtension: "") {
            do {
                let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: savedJson)
                let scryfallDecodeData = try JSONDecoder().decode([ScryfallCard].self, from: jsonData)
                return scryfallDecodeData
            } catch {
                debugPrint("decode failed")
                return []
            }
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. That's kinda what I tried at first but it kept showing a fit. But that worked perfectly.

Comment: @Zerafiall glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it. If you're unsure how to do that, you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).